# UICollectionview Number of Section like in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

In Tableviews I am using this to count how many sections should be created:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return [[[MyArray objectAtIndex:section]objectForKey:@"Rows"]count];   
}
```

Now I am trying to implement the same in a Collection view but here the code is different:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

    return 1;   
}
```

How can I achieve the same like I did in Tableviews because in this case it seems I can't use objectAtIndex?

Comment: wierd but i didn't find any option preferable  to close this question

Comment: refer this [http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12]

Comment: Seems to be not my day. So stupid. Sorry

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Table views have two methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Collection views also have two methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

So the interface works the same way in both cases.